# Pre_Save reciever not updating item's stock

Tags: django, django-models

I have a cart item model and I want it to decrease the stock when the ordered field is set to true but I don't think I'm doing it right.

CartItem model:

```
class CartItem(models.Model):
     user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                         on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
     size = models.ForeignKey(Size, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
     quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
```

My Pre_save receiver:

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=CartItem)
def decrease_stock_receiver(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if instance.ordered is True:
        print("check stock: " + str(instance.size.stock))
        instance.size.stock -= instance.quantity
        print("decrease stock: " + str(instance.size.stock))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to update the foreign object after so only direct field of instance(Caritem) will be saved . that's why you need to get the size objects and then update its stock. Try to use below code

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=CartItem)
def decrease_stock_receiver(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if instance.ordered is True:
        print("check stock: " + str(instance.size.stock))
        size = instance.size
        size.stock -= instance.quantity
        size.save()
```

This [Link](https://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-orm-cookbook/en/latest/update_denormalized_fields.html) might be helpful.